# beamer templating - baselineskip of \fontsize ignored

Tags: beamer

Can anyone explain why the second argument in `\fontsize` `\textbox` in the example is ignored in the footer template?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fix-cm}

\newcommand\testbox{\parbox[b]{30mm}{%
        \fontsize{4mm}{10mm}\selectfont\bfseries
        A\\B}%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{test}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
    \testbox
  }%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \testbox
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. ;-)

Comment: The same effect can be observed in the `headline` template, but in the `frametitle` template, for example` the value for `\baselineskip` has the desired effect.

Comment: @egreg, well not the world I'd use. And it is more natural to set the baselineskip between to lines and having to fiddle with `\vskip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit is `\offinterlineskip` in the code that typesets the headline or footline (the effect can also be observed in the `headline` template); this is used several times when building the header/footer:

```
\def\beamer@typesetheadorfoot#1{% typeset the head or footline
  {\parskip0pt\offinterlineskip%
    \hbox{%
      \hskip-\Gm@lmargin%
      \hbox{%
        \vbox{%
          \@tempdima=\textwidth%
          \textwidth=\paperwidth%
          \hsize=\textwidth%
          \def\\{,}%
          \usebeamertemplate***{#1}%
        }}%
      \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
    }}\hfil%
}
```

and

```
 \def\@oddfoot{%
    \vbox{\offinterlineskip\hbox{\beamer@typesetheadorfoot{footline}%
    \hfil}\hbox{}}\hfil
  }%
```

in `beamerbaseframecomponents.sty`.

Comment: And what do we do to fix it? I had to go and look it up, did not know that macro

Comment: Hmm, might be worth a bug report.

Comment: @daleif I imagine one could change the settings in the definition, but this will have effects in the way the `footline` is installed by the outer themes, so a change in the definition would imply changing the way the templates are installed by the themes. Seems a lot of work.

Comment: On the other hand saying that baselineskip cannot be changed in a multiline "footline" is a strange requirement

Comment: @daleif Might be a bug, but seeing how some of the `footline` and `headline` are implemented, by stacking `beamercolorboxes` , perhaps it was a design choice (not sure, however, if it was fortunate).

Comment: Isn't there a reverse of `\offinterlineskip`, Since I have multiple lines I'm setting everything inside `minipages` anyway, I could just reset it inside the outer most minipage

Comment: Seems enough to just add `\lineskiplimit=0pt` inside the wrapping `minipage`