# Specify baselineskip in Beamer block without patching Beamer

Tags: beamer, fontsize

Using `20pt` or `40pt` makes no difference, contrary to what I expect.

In [related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255780/beamer-templating-baselineskip-of-fontsize-ignored) the advice is to modify Beamer code. Do you know if one can solve it without? (e.g. `\normalbaselines` did not help)

MWE (tried in OverLeaf):

```latex
\documentclass[final,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{Author1, Author2}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{Test block}
        {\normalbaselines \fontsize{10pt}{20pt} \selectfont   \lipsum[100]}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The baseline distance depends on the value active at the end of a paragraph. Because of your braces the baselineskip value is reset to early. If you remove them it works as expected:

```
\documentclass[final,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Title}
\author{Author1, Author2}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{block}{Test block}
        \normalbaselines \fontsize{10pt}{20pt} \selectfont   \lipsum[100]
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will the font properties be reset in the next block? Or do I have to reset them manually somehow?

Comment: why don't you try?

Comment: Without braces, font props seem to be reset in the next block. But if I use `\normalbaselines \fontsize{10pt}{1pt} \selectfont` inside block->itemize->item, baselineskip change does not work